# Struggling to get imgur authorisation in react native:

Tags: react-native, deep-linking, imgur

Here is my code:, the auth webview open but then when i click allow with my account i can see in console i receive the access token but with an error, i would just like to receive the url in my AuthWebView.js then i can parse it:

> Can't open url: epicture://status#access_token=94de672d6210f6ceecfe07efd5d62728c96b8e33&expires_in=315360000&token_type=bearer&refresh_token=cfb46e86a33f4a0cd92e1596335ac21393d13251&account_username=nmateotest&account_id=140192947

code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { WebView } from "react-native-webview";
import { Linking } from "react-native";
import { API_URL, API_CLIENT_ID } from "@env";
import APIToken from "./../api/APIToken";

export default class AuthWebView extends Component {
  navigate = async (url) => {
    if (url) {
      console.log(url);
      url = url.replace("#", "&");
      let params = {};
      const regex = /([^&=]+)=([^&]*)/g;
      let m;

      while ((m = regex.exec(url))) {
        parameters[decodeURIComponent(m[1])] = decodeURIComponent(m[2]);
      }
      await APIToken.saveToken("BearerToken", parameters.access_token);
      await APIToken.saveToken("username", parameters.account_username);
      this.props.navigation.navigate("App");
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
      this.navigate(url);
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        source={{
          uri:
            API_URL +
            "oauth2/authorize?client_id=" +
            API_CLIENT_ID +
            "&response_type=token",
        }}
      />
    );
  }
```